# Deleting overlapping shapes (with Geometry Nodes)

Tags: geometry-nodes, geometry

I'm using *Geometry Nodes* to instance shapes in my scene and I'm trying to figure out if those instances overlap with another specific object. For the sake of simplicity, the specific object is a cube . *If* the instances do overlap, I'd like to delete the entire instance – not just the non-overlapping geometry (generated by the boolean operation).

My approach involves using a *Mesh Boolean* node and then testing if the point count is non-zero (using a *Domain Size* node). For this approach to work, I've had to realize instances. Here's what my node tree looks like:

[image]

Unfortunately, this doesn't work as expected. I'm guessing since I'm trying to delete the geometry that's generated further back in the chain, still stored as instance data. If I connect the output of the *Mesh Boolean* object, to *Delete Geometry*, I get the boolean difference but that leaves some artifacts that I don't want in the scene.

[image: Blender Geometry Node graph]

I know that you can use attributes to access data down the chain but is there anyway to send data from a realized mesh back to an instanced mesh?

Thanks for any tips/advice you can share!

Comment: I just realized the Boolean Mesh node should be set to "Intersect", not "Difference" (must have changed it along the way) but that still doesn't solve the issue.

Comment: It looks like what's happening is that the patch deletes all of the instances or none of the instances (depending on whether or not any overlaps occur).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If, as shown in your example, you are really only dealing with upright cubic shapes, then the node `Raycast` may help you.

With it you can check in this case, and without the computationally intensive process with `Mesh Boolean`, if another object crosses the path somewhere on the Z-axis.

Something like this:

[image]

Of course, you still need to use the `Realize Instances` node, since you need the individual points in this case. From each point you send a raycast up (or down). If there is a hit with another object, then you accumulate this value per mesh island and get a selection to delete the whole object.

[image]
<sub>*(Blender 3.6+)*</sub>

Comment: Thank you! I plan to use more complex shapes than cubes–but I do plan to use bounding boxes for testing, so this approach could work for me. Thanks for putting together a Blender file for me. I will definitely give this a try.

Comment: I did manage to get this to work in Blender 3.6 using Simulation Nodes and baking. Instead of creating all of the instances at once, I added them 1 at a time in random positions and only added a shape to the scene if it did not overlap with a specific other shape.

Comment: @Mantissa Could you please write your solution as an answer to this? ...or you mark this answer as "Accepted Answer" so that the question appears as solved. Thank you!